# How to reference static resources from a Community HTML header in a cache-compatible way?

Tags: community, static-resources

Communities allow you to specify an HTML document as a header. However, it's just static HTML – no VisualForce. Therefore, you can't use URLFOR() to generate cache busting URLs to static resources, and you're stuck using the "cache forever" URLs, .e.g.:

```
/community-name/resource/MyStaticResource/js/some-code.js
```

I currently use a build step that generates cache busting URLs and merges them into the HTML document any time the static resource zip is built, but I'm wondering if there's a simpler way.

Answer (score 3):

If its just a single file (so there are no issues with order of loading as this code loads the JavaScript asynchronously) you can work out the URL in JavaScript like this:

```
<script>
(function() {
    var script = document.createElement('script');
    script.src = '/community-name/resource/'
            + Date.now()
            + '/MyStaticResource/js/some-code.js';
    document.head.appendChild(script);
})();
</script>
```

Using the current date timestamp ensures the latest version of the static resource is obtained. That is the technique used in [this sample AngularJs app](https://github.com/metadaddy-sfdc/IssuesInGitHub/blob/master/metadata/staticresources/github_app_js.resource), though there the JavaScript would only be requested, cached and used once per application session. But for your use, the JavaScript would be requested and cached every time a page is opened.

If your present system works well, probably better to stick to it than use the above.